# Issue with recursive loop and nested multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have here a nested multidimensional array:

```
Array
(
[merchant] => Array
    (
        [XML_Serializer_Tag] => Array
            (
                [id] => 736
                [name] => Cadbury Gifts Direct
            )

        [prod] => Array
            (
                [XML_Serializer_Tag] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [XML_Serializer_Tag] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 88966064
                                        [pre_order] => no
                                        [web_offer] => no
                                        [in_stock] => no
                                        [stock_quantity] => 0
                                    )

                                [pId] => 608
                                [isbn] => 0000000000000
                                [text] => Array
                                    (
                                        [name] => 50% OFF 56g Creme Egg Minis
                                        [desc] => 50% OFF Creme Egg Minis in a 56g bag.
                                    )

                                [uri] => Array
                                    (
                                        [awTrack] => http://www.awin1.com/pclick.php?p=88966064&a=67702&m=736
                                        [awThumb] => http://images.productserve.com/thumb/736/88966064.jpg
                                        [awImage] => http://images.productserve.com/preview/736/88966064.jpg
                                        [mLink] => http://www.cadburygiftsdirect.co.uk/products/608-50-off-56g-creme-egg-minis.aspx
                                        [mImage] => http://www.cadburygiftsdirect.co.uk/images/thumbs/0001084.png
                                    )

                                [price] => Array
                                    (
                                        [XML_Serializer_Tag] => Array
                                            (
                                                [curr] => GBP
                                            )

                                        [buynow] => 0.31
                                        [store] => 0.00
                                        [rrp] => 0.00
                                        [delivery] => 0.00
                                    )

                                [cat] => Array
                                    (
                                        [awCatId] => 437
                                        [awCat] => Chocolate
                                        [mCat] => Full Range
                                    )

                                [brand] => 
                                [valFrom] => 0000-00-00
                                [valTo] => 0000-00-00
                                [comAmount] => 0.00
                            )
```

The segment loop afterwards.

So...

```
[1] => Array
[2] => Array
[3] => Array
```

etc...

I need to find the names of the attributes of each array segment.

So I have used this recursive loop:

```
private function recursive_array($old_array, $new_array = array()) {

    foreach ($old_array as $key => $value) {

        if (is_array($value) && $key < 1) {
            $new_array = $this->recursive_array($value, $new_array);

        } else {
            if ($key < 1) {
                $new_array[] = $key;

            }
        }
    }
    return $new_array;
}
```

This is the output:

```
array
  0 => string 'id' (length=2)
  1 => string 'name' (length=4)
  2 => string 'id' (length=2)
  3 => string 'pre_order' (length=9)
  4 => string 'web_offer' (length=9)
  5 => string 'in_stock' (length=8)
  6 => string 'stock_quantity' (length=14)
  7 => string 'pId' (length=3)
  8 => string 'isbn' (length=4)
  9 => string 'name' (length=4)
  10 => string 'desc' (length=4)
  11 => string 'awTrack' (length=7)
  12 => string 'awThumb' (length=7)
  13 => string 'awImage' (length=7)
  14 => string 'mLink' (length=5)
  15 => string 'mImage' (length=6)
  16 => string 'curr' (length=4)
  17 => string 'buynow' (length=6)
  18 => string 'store' (length=5)
  19 => string 'rrp' (length=3)
  20 => string 'delivery' (length=8)
  21 => string 'awCatId' (length=7)
  22 => string 'awCat' (length=5)
  23 => string 'mCat' (length=4)
  24 => string 'brand' (length=5)
  25 => string 'valFrom' (length=7)
  26 => string 'valTo' (length=5)
  27 => string 'comAmount' (length=9
```

What it is also picking up is the top nested array:

```
[XML_Serializer_Tag] => Array
            (
                [id] => 736
                [name] => Cadbury Gifts Direct
            )
```

This is just details for the entire feed not the individual segments.

I need a way of filtering out the top nested array but bear in mind that the details are dynamic so the name of the keys can change from one feed to the next

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this?

```
$riter = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(New RecursiveArrayIterator($array));
foreach ($riter as $key => $val) {
    if ($riter->getDepth() > 1) {
        echo "$key => $val\n";
    }
}
```

by default, RecursiveIteratorIterator only visits leaf nodes(the deepest levels down every path). getDepth() can be used to make sure were a minimum depth. I'm not sure if 1 is the correct number, but anyway...

Comment: Yes, if I set it to level two is does work on all the different types of arrays. I need to re-write my function above now because by using this method it removes the key which I was using to count (this outputs a long list of strings)

Answer (score 0):

use `array_shift` to pop off the first element of the array